# How to create a makefile for Unix

Tags: c++, unix, makefile

Ok I keep receiving the following error message:

```
g++    -c -o guess.o guess.cpp
guess.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
guess.cpp:70:7: error: expected ‘}’ at end of input
   }
   ^
guess.cpp:70:7: error: expected ‘}’ at end of input
guess.cpp:70:7: error: expected ‘}’ at end of input
make: *** [guess.o] Error 1
```

It is referring to the last part of my code which is:

```
 cout << "Think of an integer between 1 and 1000. I will try to guess it." << endl;

  bool result = doGuesses(0, 1001);
      {
  if (!result) 
               {
    cout << " and is between 1 and 1000." << endl;
    cout << "\n\nI demand a rematch!" << endl;
               } 
        }
```

I have deleted the } and added it back and I still continue to get the same error message. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are you stuck at? You have those files and what?

Comment: I can't compile the guess.cpp and yesno.cpp to create the guess.o and yesno.o files. That's the only parts holding me up from finishing

Comment: Then you need to give us the command you are running and the error output you are getting.

Comment: Sure. I'm putting in g++ -c guess.cpp yesno.cpp and this is the error I keep getting: in file included from guess.cpp:3:0: yesno.h:1:14: warning: extra tokens at end of #ifndef (enabled by dfault) #ifndf yesno.h

Comment: In file included from guess.cpp:3:0:
yesno.h:1:14: warning: extra tokens at end of #ifndef directive [enabled by default]
 #ifndef yesno.h
              ^
yesno.h:3:19: fatal error: yesno.h: No such file or directory
 #include <yesno.h>
                   ^
compilation terminated.
In file included from yesno.cpp:1:0:
yesno.h:1:14: warning: extra tokens at end of #ifndef directive [enabled by default]
 #ifndef yesno.h
              ^
yesno.h:3:19: fatal error: yesno.h: No such file or directory
 #include <yesno.h>
                   ^
compilation terminated.

Comment: Don't use comments. Update the post to remove any extraneous information and to present the relevant place you are stuck and the errors you are seeing.

Comment: Why does `yesno.h` include itself? Also `#ifndef yesno.h` should probably be `#ifndef yesno_h`.

Comment: Use `#include "yesno.h"` notation to include headers you create, reserving `<yesno.h>`  notation for standard headers such as `<algorithm>` or `<string>`.  If you decide you must use angle brackets, then the command line needs to include `-I.` in the compiler options.  Your residual errors are spelling mistakes: `respnse` --> `response` and `doGuess` --> `doGuesses`.  It is hard to be dyslexic and a programmer.

Answer (score 1):

> MAKEFILE

This looks good to me. There are a couple of issues though.

> ```
> guess:yesno.o guess.o
>     g++ guess yesno.o guess.o
> ```

`g++` needs the `-o` option to name the output file. It's the same syntax as if you'd run it in the command line. And I'd put a space after the colon. But I'm not sure if that's mandatory.

> ```
> guess.o: yesno.h
> yesno.o: yesno.h
> ```

*guess.o* and *yesno.o* also need the dependency with their respective cpp files.

Like this:

```
guess.o: guess.cpp yesno.h
```

Comment: Great. So I went in and added the -o to my make file. When I try to compile the file I get this error:

Comment: in file included from guess.cpp. fatal error. I cant compile the guess.cpp and yesno.cpp. What am I still doing wrong?

Comment: Try `g++ -c guess.cpp` and `g++ -c yesno.cpp` in your rules.  The `-c` tells `g++` to create a `.o` file.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews that's not needed. `make` has implicit rules for `.o` targets.

Comment: Thanks anyways. Still trying to figure out my error

Answer (score 1):

The errors speak for themselves.

Your include guard tries to test an invalid macro name, `yesno.h`. It should be `yesno_h`, to match the following definition.

Your header tries to include itself, but as a system header. It shouldn't do that.

You want something more like

```
#ifndef yesno_h
#define yesno_h

// Return true if response is "yes", "y", or any upper/lowercase
// variant of those two strings.
bool yesNo (std::string response);

#endif
```

Comment: I modified it and I still get an error. Should I also modify the guess.cpp and yesno.cpp files to match?

Comment: @miss_sparkles: I don't know what you mean by "modify to match", since they have nothing that should match the header. Read the error message and, if you can't understand it, ask a question about that.

Comment: When I type in "make" to attempt to compile the files, it tells me yesno.h No such file or directory. #include <yesno.h>. compilation terminated.

Comment: @miss_sparkles: It should be `"yesno.h"` not `<yesno.h>` since it's not a system header. Also, make sure the header really exists, and really is called `"yesno.h"`. (The posted code suggests you've got this right, except where I already mentioned that the header tries to incorrectly reinclude itself, so I guess your real code doesn't match what you posted.)

Comment: Cool. And what does it mean when it says string is not a member of std

Comment: That generally means you didn't `#include <string>` at the top of one of your cpp files.